# set value for span using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<li>` which have a field named  `data-resultcount`.I need to select the `data-resultcount`  value and print in the span.My `<li>` is

```
  <li id="totalCount" style="display:none" data-total="19" data-resultcount="19">totalCount</li>
```

and the `<span>` is

```
<div class="resultCount">Results:
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.resultCount span').text($('#totalCount').attr('data-resultcount'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

html:

```
<div class="resultCount">Results:
    <span id ="mySpan"></span>
</div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML="Span text is changed";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.data()` to fetch value from `data-resultcount`

```
$('.resultCount').find('span').text($('#totalCount').data('resultcount'))
```

or

```
$('.resultCount span').text($('#totalCount').data('resultcount'))
```

Comment: +1 for `$('.resultCount').find('span')` ,`$('.resultCount span')` will be penalty in perf

Answer (score 1):

This will work :

```
$('.resultCount span').text($('li#totalCount').attr('data-resultcount'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$(".resultCount").find('span:first').text($("#totalCount").attr('data-resultcount'))
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/xtpg3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)method for better result:

```
$('.resultCount span').text($('li#totalCount').prop('data-resultcount'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".resultCount").find('span').text($("#totalCount").attr('data-resultcount'))
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtpg3/17/)